# coordinates min distance c++

Tags: c++, distance, min, coordinate

Im currently having a small problems , because i need to find the coordinates corresponded to my min distance. 
For example i have a person and three potential stations. I need to find the distance between them and then take the min distance and in the next i have to take the coordinates related to that min distance.
Im sending you my loop just for that part of my program.

```
for (newCoordinate = newPoints.begin(); newCoordinate != newPoints.end(); newCoordinate++)// here are my three potential stations
{
    distanceBetweenBusCoordinateAndNewPoint = sqrt(pow((busRequest->x - newCoordinate->x), 2) + (pow((busRequest->y - newCoordinate->y), 2)));// find min
    distances.push_back(distanceBetweenBusCoordinateAndNewPoint);//add to the vector
}
newdis = min_element(distances.begin(), distances.end());// find the min of min
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: as i said , i need the coordinates related to that min distance . I have 3 distances and 3 coordinates (x,y) . I find the min of them and need to save the coordinates because after i take these coordinates i find another tasks.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for squaring things; multiply them.  The `pow` function has a lot more execution overhead than a simple multiply.

Answer (score 0):

I would treat this as finding a minimum value in a `std::vector`.

One variable contains the minimum distance; initialized to the largest value.
Two `Point` variables define the straight line associated with the minimum distance.

Here's an algorithm:

```
Calculate distance.  
if distance < minimum distance  
    set Point1 and Point2 to the ordinates used in the distance calculation.  
    set minimum distance to the calculated distance.
```

At the end of the loop, the variables `Point1` and `Point2` will be the coordinates associated with the `minimum distance`.

Comment: Yes i understand what you mean but my fault that i didn't add one more thing. For example i find some coordinates associated with min distance. Then my first loop at the beginning i didn't post it iterates a new person and i need to do the same procedure for that person. Here is the problem , i have already Min value = previous min distance. So if the distance of that second person is larger than mean , he won't be added at all.. So i need the solution.   I find the coordinates of a station for the first person and then i need to find the new coordinates for the second person if he can reach

Comment: the station of the first one.Hope it is quite clear what my program should do. I did everything right but the problem is just here. My Min value can become too low and then those people won't have any station but i need to check all the time , if that person can't reach the previous one or any , that person should have a new station with new coordinates even if the distance is larger than the Min value after some iterations

Comment: Because i have  already done as you posted. But by the way thanks for your comment